# How to set up a paging horizontal UIScrollView with a UITextView on top of it

Tags: ios, swift, uiscrollview, uitextview

In my app I have a screen where you can amend text in a UITextView, and swipe left and right in a UIScrollview with isPagingEnabled set to true, to change the background of the screen. How do I get the horizontal movement ONLY to be transferred to the back UIScrollview, while preserving the paging behaviour?

Comment: Instead of scrollview you can use UICollectionView, as its delegates methods will do all tasks what you want..

Comment: @Sakshi I agree. You can use a UICollectionView or. a TableviewController with a customTableViewCell that contains a UIViewController inside of it. Other thing is to usee a third party library like AirBnb's https://github.com/airbnb/AloeStackView

Comment: Yes, you can use any 3rd party library.But making use of collectionview will makes things totally controlled in your hands while on other hand using 3rd party,any change required will be dependent on that library.